# Query to find simultaneous task performed by the same person

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with 4 columns, ID, name, starttime, endtime.
[[image: Table1]]

I need to find for each procedure the number of simultaneous procedures performed by the anaesthesian.

The output should be the Proc_id with count of simultaneous procedures.
This is similar to the the expected output.

[image]

How do i query this?

Comment: can you define how to calculate *simultaneous procedures* and show us your attempt?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala simultaneous procedures based on time, I'll try to post my attempts if I'm close to anywhere near

Comment: it is tough to answer when you don't even post the expected output

Comment: ok, ill post the expected output!.

Comment: Unclear if you want to lists procedures that are running simultaneously on the exact same timeframe (ie which have the same start and end time), or if you want those that run simultaneously at certain point of time (it can be only 1 second)?

Comment: @ThomasG I want the count of procedures that are running simultaneously in between the time frame

Comment: What does "4" only appear for `proc_id` 40?  There are 4 procedures running simultaneously, so all four should have a value of "4".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a range from start and end time using something like

```
tsrange (start_time, end_time, '[]')  (for exclusive range boundaries)
tsrange (start_time, end_time, '()')  (for inclusive range boundaries)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/rangetypes.html

Use the overlaps operator '&&' to test 2 ranges

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-range.html

Wrap it up in a query that may look like this

```
SELECT p1.proc_id,
( SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM procedure p2 
WHERE p1.anest_name = p2.anest_name 
  AND p1.proc_id <> p2.proc_id
  AND tsrange (p1.start_time, p1.end_time, '()') && tsrange (p2.start_time, p2.end_time,'()')
) as count 
FROM procedure p1
ORDER BY p1.proc_id
```

What kind of range boundaries you use, depends on your understanding of "simultaneous". That may mean overlapping, contained by another timeframe or something else. You may want to fiddle around with the boundaries, but that query should match your estimated results (or at least come close to them) ...